# Group by dynamic string array keys without anonymous type or strong type

Tags: c#, linq

Here is a table data like:

```
Age Country Name
25 Indocin David 
25 Indocin Sam 
21 Hydralazine Christoff 
21 Hydralazine Janet 
100 Dilantin Melanie
```

I can use `group by Anonymous Type` to group the data by multiple keys

```cs
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David");
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "Sam");
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Hydralazine", "Christoff");
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Hydralazine", "Janet");
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie");


    var gt = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .GroupBy(g => new { Age = g["Age"] , Country = g["Country"]   });
}
```

But, I expect to use `string key array` to dynamic get same group data.

```cs
var groupkey = new[] {"Age","Country"};
var gt = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(g => SomeMethod(g,groupkey));
```

below code what i have tried,but it's not work for group `"Age","Country"` :

```
    var groupkeys = new[] {"Age","Country"};
    var gt = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .GroupBy(g => {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();
            foreach (var key in groupkeys)
            {
                dictionary.Add(key,g[key]);
            }
            return dictionary;
        });
```

#### My answer

following @Gauravsa 's logic,i can do it with below code :

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David");
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "Sam");
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Hydralazine", "Christoff");
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Hydralazine", "Janet");
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie");

    var groupkeys = new[] { "Age", "Country" };
    var gt = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .GroupBy(g => new GroupKey(groupkeys, g));
}

public class GroupKey
{
    public string[] keys { get; set; }
    public DataRow dr { get; set; }

    public GroupKey(string[] _keys, DataRow _dr)
    {
        this.keys = _keys;
        this.dr = _dr;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hash = 0;
            foreach (var key in keys)
                hash += dr[key].GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;

        return Equals((GroupKey)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(GroupKey other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        return other.GetHashCode() == this.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can create a class first of datatable column names and implement equals and hashcode method

Comment: @Gauravsa thanks first,but i expect using dynamic string keys to do it without creating a class.

Comment: groupby works on default equalitycomparer. it doesnt work on referencetypes

Comment: referencetypes works on checking for referential integrity and will return false in your case.

Comment: yes , you are right , can u answer below then i'll mark it answer, @Gauravsa

Comment: updated the answer. pls see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a GroupKeys class and override Equals and GetHashCode or you can implement IEquatable. This one generated by Resharper:

```
private class GroupKey
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Key1 != null ? Key1.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (Key2 != null ? Key2.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;

        return Equals((GroupKey)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(GroupKey other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return string.Equals(Key1, other.Key1)
               && string.Equals(Key2, other.Key2);
    }
}
```

Now, you can do groupby like below:

```
var groupkey = new[] {"Age","Country"};
GroupKey key = new GroupKey ();
key.Key1 = "Age";
key.Key2 = "Country";

var gt = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(g => groupKey)
        .Select(g => new GroupKey
        {
            Key1 = g.Key.Key1,
            Key2 = g.Key.Key2            
});
```

Groupby works on default [EqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_EqualityComparer_1_Default). it doesnt work on referencetypes. Referencetypes works on checking for referential integrity and will return false in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to create a `Key` at first:

```
var gt = from p in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
         group p by p["Age"] into g
         select new { Age = g.Key, Other = g.Select(s => s) };
```

UPDATE:

```
var gt = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .GroupBy(g => $"{g["Age"]} {g["Country"]}")
            .Select(g => new
            {
                   g.Key
                ,  Persons = g.Select(s=> s["Name"]).ToList()
            });
```

Comment: it's not my expection. but thanks ,i have upvoted this asnwer.

Comment: @Wei, please, see my updated answer. Or could you write the expected output?

Comment: @Wei is output okay for you?

Comment: sorry it's not work. it's demo link : dotnetfiddle.net/bhg4Qi